# What object is this?

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth, connectivity

In the bluetooth documentation there is a code sample to explain the functionning of J2ME with bluetooth. The code uses BCC , perhaps Bluetooth Control Center, and the methods it calls are not included in the javadoc. Here is the url of the code sample : [code sample](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/)

I looked at javadoc but I did not find the first three method.

So what is the BCC ? And how to create it ?

Comment: it seems from looking at the article that BCC is api associated with Blue tooth devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you link to specifically states:

> The underlying Bluetooth system upon which the Java APIs will be built must also meet certain requirements:
>
> - The underlying system must be "qualified," in accordance with the Bluetooth Qualification Program, for at least the Generic Access Profile, Service Discovery Application Profile, and Serial Port Profile.
> - The system must support three communication layers or protocols as defined in the 1.1 Bluetooth Specification, and the implementation of this API must have access to them: Service Discovery Protocol (SDP), Radio Frequency Communications Protocol (RFCOMM), and Logical Link Control and Adaptation Protocol (L2CAP).
> - **The system must provide a Bluetooth Control Center (BCC), a control panel much like the application that allows a user or OEM to define specific values for certain configuration parameters in a stack.**

You won't have to create a BCC: the system must provide one. Furthermore:

> What Is the BCC?
>
> Bluetooth devices that implement this API may allow multiple applications to execute concurrently. The BCC prevents any application from harming another. The BCC is a set of capabilities that allow a user or OEM to resolve conflicting application requests by defining specific values for certain configuration parameters in a Bluetooth stack. It is the central authority for local Bluetooth device settings. The BCC might be a native application, an application with a separate API, or simply a group of settings that are specified by the manufacturer and cannot be changed by the user. Note that the BCC is not a class or an interface defined in this specification but an important part of its security architecture.

The code-sample you point to is:

```
// set the port number
BCC.setPortNumber("COM1");
// set the baud rate
BCC.setBaudRate(50000);
// set the connectable mode
BCC.setConnectable(true);
// set the discovery mode to Limited Inquiry Access Code
BCC.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.LIAC);
```

However, the article states above this example:

> As an example, Atinav's Java Bluetooth solution requires the developer to initialize the stack with a series of settings like the ones in the following code snippet - **note well that the APIs invoked are not part of JSR 82**.

Comment: If so why cannot I compile the sample codes inside my emulator even if I import javax.microedition.bluetooth and javax.microedition.obex ?

Comment: Because the `BCC` in the code-example is only for vendor-specific BCC's. This is also emulator specific. See http://www.microemu.org/: it has a bluetooth API using BlueCove or avetana JSR-82 implementations.